# Getting the index of a 2D numpy array according to a 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working with numpy arrays I hit a roadblock, maybe you can help me. So I have a 2D numpy array, each array in this 2D array has a max value, what I need is get the index of the max value but not of the 2D array, instead, use the index like it was a 1D array, I know I can use `numpy.argmax` to find the index, but the index it's according to the 2D array not an 1D array, maybe an example would be better:

```
import numpy as np

arr =  np.array([[512, 523, 491], 
                 [512, 531, 495]])

index = np.argmax(arr, axis = 1)
index2 = np.argmax(arr)

print(index)
print(index2) 

index = [1, 1] 
index2 = 4
```

I mean it does what it's supposed to do, but what if I need the index like it was a 1D array? This is my desired output:

```
index = [1, 4]
```

So the first max value is 523 so the first index is 1, and the second max value is 531 so the second index is 4 according like it was a 1D array. Maybe this is a newbie question, but I'm not sure how to do this and this is just an example, the `arr` array can be bigger, so, any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing I could think to do is add an offset to index.

```
offset = np.arange(0,arr.shape[0]*arr.shape[1], arr.shape[1])
index1D = offset + index
```

for context, np.arange takes 3 args: start, stop, and stride. so the offset is just  adding the total number of elements before a particular row to the index.

Comment: Oh I see it now! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The first line is actually what you wanted. It returns the index of the max in each nested array, i.e. `531` is in index 1 of the second nested array.

You can use that with advanced indexing as

```
>>> print(arr[np.arange(arr.shape[0]), index])
[523, 531]
```

Or change index to a flat index

```
flat_index = index + np.arange(0, arr.size, arr.shape[1])
# flat_index == [1, 4]
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I get it now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could add offsets to each element, given that you know the dimensions of the 2D array.

e.g.

```
index = [1, 1]
offset = [0, 3]

index + offset
>>> [1, 4]
```

You can get the offsets quite easily by doing `np.arange(len(index))*size`. Where size is the width of the 2D array.